# There is no email program associated

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to install Outlook 2010 pro 32 bit on my W7 32 bit machine.

I have created the email account, which sends/receives, but, every time I load up Outlook, I get the same message

[image]

I have right clicked on the .pst file to say always use Outlook (I made no change, as it already was open with Outlook)
I have gone into Program and features and clicked Change on MS Office, and clicked repair
I changed the default program as per http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Change-the-default-e-mail-program
I deleted the entry in the registry as per http://www.thewindowsclub.com/there-is-no-email-program-associated-outlook
I made sure it wasn't in compatibility mode as per http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/there-is-no-email-program-associated-to-perform/31f0cd13-dfe8-4ee7-a836-bd82cc6008cb

The above make no difference.

As mentioned, Outlook functions well, but, how do I avoid seeing this message every time I open Outlook or every time I click on a different account within Outlook

Comment: I am confused the reason you configure .pst to have a default program when its not that type of file and likely the reason your getting this warning message.

Comment: @Ramhound, I didn't . I right clicked on the .PST to to associate it. However, when I chose open with, Outlook was already selected, so I made no change. So, the pst file shows the Outlook icon.

Comment: You don't need to associate a .pst to outlook since its very rare you actually would attempt to open a .pst even if you do your better of doing it through Outlook not trying to access the file like a normal file.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, that is interesting to know but alas, I don't think it sheds any light onto my issue. The problem occurred first, not my trying to create an association... Actually, I've just realised you can't even open the .pst file from Windows Explorer.